# How to check if a Java EE Singleton is busy?

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton, javabeans

I have a long-lasting method in a Singleton Java EE 6 bean.

How could I see "from outside" whether that Singleton is currently busy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could within that method change the object attribute(flag), to indicate the method is under execution.

from outside, you could do object.getBusyFlag() to decide.

however if you are trying to make the method thread-safe, you could consider **synchronized** keyword.

Comment: As it is a Singleton, the bean is locked during method runtime. The getBusyFlag() would run AFTER the main method exits.

Comment: Used a static variable "busy" instead of a function to get around the locking problem. One could use bean managed concurrency to fix it, too, I guess. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Kent is right. Moreover if the 'flag' is just a Boolean value, you can declare it as 'volatile' and don't use 'synchronized'.